# Sklearn LogisticRegression predict_proba result look weird

Tags: scikit-learn

I am quite new to SKlearn, Machine learning and its related. I have searched for a day but still cannot figure out the answer.

```
model = LogisticRegression(C=1)
model.fit(X, y)
print(model.predict_proba(X_test))
// output
[[  1.01555532e-08   2.61926230e-01   7.37740949e-01   3.32810963e-04]]
```

I am quite confused whether the output is correct or not. When I tried on SVM with the same dataset, I got `[[ 0.21071225  0.42531172  0.01024818  0.35372784]]` which looks like probability and this is what I want. How can I make LogisticRegression model get the same probability style like SVM? What do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just printing-style!

Have a look at this demo:

Code:

```python
import numpy as np

p = np.array([[  1.01555532e-08,   2.61926230e-01,   7.37740949e-01,   3.32810963e-04]])
print('p: ', p)
print('sum: ', p.sum())                         # approximately a probability-distribution?

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
print('p: ', p)                                 # same print as above
                                                # but printing-style was changed before!
```

Output:

```
p:  [[1.01555532e-08 2.61926230e-01 7.37740949e-01 3.32810963e-04]]
sum:  1.0000000001185532
p:  [[0.00000001 0.26192623 0.73774095 0.00033281]]
```

Numpy uses a lot of code to decide on how to print your arrays, depending on the values inside! Here we changed something, using [np.set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

Your output looks different, because the output of your SVM-prediction has no small values, like the other one did!

> suppress : bool, optional
>
> Whether or not suppress printing of small floating point values using scientific notation (default False).

The use of scientific-notation also applies to python's types:

```
x = 0.00000001
print(x)
# 1e-08
```